# User: Editor, can't see edit taxonomy screen

Tags: custom-taxonomy, user-roles, capabilities

For some reason the Editor role does not get access to the edit taxonomy screen on my site. Maybe that is expected behavior, I dont know - But how can I add this to the editor role capabilities?

Comment: Johan, Questions and Answers are different creatures. You can answer your own question & the button has this very name... I suspect someone hasn't read the FAQ ;)

Comment: Sorry, I fixed it. Will read the FAQ now :)

Answer (score 1):

Right after I wrote the posts I found it...anyway if someone else is looking for the answer to this, you need to set capabilities when you register your taxonomy. You add the following:

```
    'capabilities' => array (
    'manage_terms' => 'edit_posts', 
    'edit_terms' => 'edit_posts',
    'delete_terms' => 'edit_posts',
    'assign_terms' => 'edit_posts'  
    )
```

edit_posts means administrator', 'editor', 'author' and 'contributor'.

Comment: Note that plugins can alter the default roles and add new roles with any mix of capabilities. That said edit_posts is a good cap if you want all authors to be able to edit the taxonomy. Make sure they can't delete taxonomy terms unless you want them to.